# Which spectrum of hydrogen is predicted by Maxwell's equations?

Tags: maxwell-equations, spectroscopy, hydrogen

Which spectrum of hydrogen is predicted by Maxwell's equations? Assuming no Lorentz force, or protons and electrons are forced to not crush on each other and be at the right distance apart.

Was this situation described anywhere? Is there a software to simulate it?

The downvotes don't clarify anything unfortunately.

UPDATE: the Lorentz force is turned off, so that electron and proton don't collapse on each other, and are kept at their usual distance. What absorption spectrum is expected in that situation?

Comment: The question asks the H2 spectrum without QM, it looks perfectly valid to me.

Comment: Before voting, please check the comments below @MarkoLeljak's answer.

Comment: Maxwell's equations do not predict a discrete set of states for an electron/proton pair so there would not be a discrete spectrum. All you would get is a continuous emission due to bremsstrahlung radiation. Is this what you are asking about? If so can you clarify your question to say so?

Answer (score 2):

None. Maxwell's equations are completely classical equations which predict that the electron should spiral towards the nucleus, emitting higher and higher frequencies as its angular speed increases. To predict atomic spectra you need quantum mechanics.

Comment: That spiral radiates, and that radiation has a spectrum.  Perhaps that's the question.

Comment: Maybe it is, the question is not 100% clear.

Comment: The question is not terribly clear indeed.

Comment: Something like Bohr model? I think is asking for that. Maybe.